# Run a script in background in php using shell_exec

Tags: php, cron, background-process, shell-exec

I was running a php script in background, and what I tried:

```
shell_exec('nohup php C:\wamp\www\Management_software\application\views\testcron.php  > /dev/null & echo $!');
```

This is working fine when I opened up the command prompt(`cmd`) and tried:

```
php C:\wamp\www\Management_software\application\views\testcron.php
```

But this is not working from the php page, how to solve this or any other techniques or what are the modifications I have to make ?

Comment: Are you getting any error???

Comment: Nope am getting nothing  in my php page , But in cmd am getting the output

Answer (score 2):

This might help you debug the problem. [**exec**](https://www.php.net/function.exec) can take 3 arguments and those help in identifying what's going on.

Try with

```
exec('nohup php C:\wamp\www\Management_software\application\views\testcron.php  > /dev/null & echo $!', $op, $er); 
echo $er;`
```

and see what gets printed on the page. If the value of `$er` is greater than 0, then something is wrong.

For list of exit codes, refer [**this list**](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html)

Comment: The value of $er is 0

Comment: That means the command executed successfully. Whatever was written in `testcron.php` was completed. So if it had, for example say, an insertion into the database you could verify it by looking it up in the table.

Comment: Yeah i have an insert command ,But its not working actually .

Comment: Well i have to add anything in php.ini , inorder to work , 'exec' and 'shell_exec' functions ?

Comment: Well It worked , there was no writing permission on the file !